# Using \iupac{\D} or \D in a \paragraph{} environment

Tags: chemmacros

How can I use the `\D` or `\iupac{\D}` command from `chemmacros` package in a `\paragraph` environment? The result I get is a lower case d instead of the D- for the Fischer stereo descriptor.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrreprt}  
\usepackage{chemmacros}  

\begin{document}  
\paragraph{\D-Proline}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you sure, that the font you are using does actually have a bold-face+smallCaps letter D. Try loading package `libertine` and test again.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Please give as a minimal working example which makes it much easier for us to help. Just your documentclass, the paragraph, your macro...

Comment: Ok, thanks, I suppose I am using an inappropriate document class/font to include this type of character in titles/paragraphs... is there a possibility to include the Fischer descriptors anyway or is it best to use another document class or font?

Comment: As @Johannes_B says, the issue here isn't `\D` or `chemmacros` _per se_, but the fact that your document class is picking a font which doesn't have sanserif bold small caps. The question then is what you want to change: the font, the use of sanserif, ...

Comment: BTW, you do know that `\paragraph` is (a) a command, not an environment and (b) a _sectioning_ command like `\section` or `\chapter`, yes?

Comment: Alright I'll try using another font, thank you. Sorry for using the wrong description, I know how to use the command.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As already noted in the comments the “problem” is that you don't use a font with bold sans serif small caps. Indeed, your example produces in the log file

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmss/bx/sc' undefined
```

You have a few choices to circumvent the issue:

- use a font that has bold face sans serif small caps (such as Linux Biolinum, the accompanying sans serif to Linux Libertine, for example)

  ```
  \documentclass[a4paper]{scrreprt}  
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage{libertine} % <<<<

  \usepackage{chemmacros}  

  \begin{document}  
  \paragraph{\iupac{\D-Proline}}  
  \end{document}
  ```
- use standard fonts but change the headings fonts from sans serif to serif

  ```
  \documentclass[a4paper]{scrreprt}  
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \setkomafont{sectioning}{\bfseries} % <<<<

  \usepackage{chemmacros}  

  \begin{document}  
  \paragraph{\iupac{\D-Proline}}  
  \end{document}
  ```
- change the definitions of `\D` to `\L` so they don't use small caps any more, e.g. with the `relsize` package:

  ```
  \documentclass[a4paper]{scrreprt}  
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

  \usepackage{relsize} % <<<<
  \usepackage{chemmacros}  
  \RenewChemIUPAC\D{\textsmaller{D}} % <<<<
  \RenewChemIUPAC\L{\textsmaller{L}} % <<<<

  \begin{document}  
  \paragraph{\iupac{\D-Proline}}  
  \end{document}
  ```